# Sql Server 2012, Finding mismatch between two tables based on non primary key

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out how to find the difference between two tables that do not have a primary/unique key. In the below example I need to join Table1 and Table2 based on id and id1 columns to compare Value field in both table. As you see in the example below Table1 has Value D that do not match with the last row of table2.

```
create table Table1 (id int, id1 int, value varchar(10))
create table Table2 (id int, id1 int, value varchar(10))
insert into Table1 values (1,2,'A'),(1,2,'A'),(1,2,'B'),(1,2,'C'),(1,2,'D')
insert into Table2 values (1,2,'A'),(1,2,'A'),(1,2,'B'),(1,2,'C'),(1,2,'C')
```

**Table1 :**

```
id        id1      value
----------------------------
1         2          A
----------------------------
1         2          A
----------------------------
1         2          B
----------------------------
1         2          C
----------------------------
1         2          D
----------------------------
```

**Table2:**

```
id        id1      value
----------------------------
1         2          A
----------------------------
1         2          A
----------------------------
1         2          B
----------------------------
1         2          C
----------------------------
1         2          C
----------------------------
```

I want the output to show the entry that is different between the two tables, as shown below:

```
id          id1         Table1.value   Table2.value
-----------------------------------------------------
1           2           D              C
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the below code but i am not sure if this works if the any of the tables have duplicate `select * from 
(select Binary_Checksum(id,id1) B ,Value,Row_Number() over(partition by Binary_Checksum(id,id1) order by value asc) RID from Table1) L
inner join 
(select Binary_Checksum(id,id1) B ,Value,Row_Number() over(partition by Binary_Checksum(id,id1) order by value asc) RID from Table2 ) N
on L.B = N.B and L.RID = N.RID where L.Value <> N.Value`

Comment: formatting and clarification of desired output